# How to read one week,one month logs data using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Currently capturing battery data in `csv` format file. File should be maximum 50k lines. After reach maximum lines file should be delete first saved lines, this logic and file writing completed, When user required one week , one month data should read data and write in to another file, I searched in google i got sample script file but not working.

Sample input log data:

```
"10/07/2020     03:37   battery 90"
"13/07/2020     03:39   battery 90"
"17/07/2020     03:41   battery 90"
"17/07/2020     03:44   battery 90"
```

Expected one week log data:

```
"13/07/2020     03:39   battery 90"
"17/07/2020     03:41   battery 90"
"17/07/2020     03:44   battery 90"
```

Currently using shell script:

```
x=$(($1*24*3600))

last=$(tail -n1 batteryLogs.csv|awk -F'[][]' '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; print d;}' )

awk -F'[][]' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0}' batteryLogs.csv
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Am I understanding correctly that you would like to extract the last _n_ days available in a log-file? Or are you interested in the data of the last _n_ days with respect to today (not last entry of log-file?

Comment: Yes, I need last n days data from today

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62992780/4162356

Comment: I only posted but not explain properly in stackoverflow.com/q/62992780/4162356, I dont have any knowledge in script, just i tried google example.